# Остановить выполнение программы Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

На форме две кнопки - Button1 и Button2. В Button1, при нажатии - выполняется цикл, чтение текстового, обработка и сохранения результата.

**Как можно реализовать:** Остановить выполнение цикла при нажатии на кнопку Button2:

```
    var f1,f2:TextFile;
    s:string;
    i:integer;
    ...................................
    ///////////////Я так поняла где то вот тут нужно вставить условие ?
    while not Eof(f1) do begin
Application.ProcessMessages; /////// что бы программа не зависала
            Readln(f1,s);
    s := AnsiUpperCase(s);
    Writeln(f2,s);
    end;
    CloseFile(f1);
    CloseFile(f2);
    end;
```

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov, За ответ благодарна, а вот вопрос: Почему Application.ProcessMessages вредная и опасная функция ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Выбросить `Application.ProcessMessages` как одну из самых вредных и опасных функций.
2. Перенести выполнение кода `Button1Click` в отдельный поток
3. Условие цикла

   ```
   while not Eof(f1) do begin
   ```

   заменить на

   ```
   while not Terminated and not Eof(f1) do begin
   ```
4. В обработчике `Button2Click` написать `MyThread.Terminate;`

Comment: За ответ благодарна, а вот вопрос: Почему Application.ProcessMessages вредная и опасная функция ?

Comment: Вредная, потому, что отучает думать и провоцирует сделать как быстрее, а не как правильнее (вторая такая функция - `Sleep` кроме как для отладки, да и то в исключительных случаях). А опасная, потому, что во время выполнения цикла, форма активна и ее можно, например, закрыть или нажать кнопку запуска еще раз. Что тогда произойдет с вашим циклом?

Comment: Anton Shchyrov, дельный совет. Учту вашу информацию.